# Error: unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing

Tags: arrays, matrix, indexing

I have a list of variables name "comorbid_names". And I want to select people who have those comorbidities in "comorbidities". However, I want to select the variable names if they are true.

For example patient 1 has "chd" only, therefore only that will be displayed as TRUE

> comorbid_names
>    [1] "chd"                         "heart_failure"               "stroke"
>    [4] "hypertension"                "diabetes"                    "copd"
>    [7] "epilepsy"                    "hypothyroidism"              "cancer"
>   [10] "asthma"                      "ckd_stage3"                  "ckd_stage4"
>   [13] "ckd_stage5"                  "atrial_fibrilation"          "learning_disability"
>   [16] "peripheral_arterial_disease" "osteoporosis"
>   class(comorbid_names)
>   [1] "character"

comorbidities <- names(p[, comorbid_names][p[, comorbid_names] == 1])

At this point I get this error

Error: Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing

I am not entirely sure why, but I think it's to do with comorbid_names being character

Does anyone have an advice?

Comment: Hi @Rospa- if any of the answers you got solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 16):

If `p` is a `tibble` as opposed to or in addition to a `data.frame`, you might be dealing with the following:

https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/

Look at the bottom of the post:

> Interacting with legacy code
>
> A handful of functions are don’t work with tibbles because they expect df[, 1] to return a vector, not a data frame. If you encounter one of these functions, use as.data.frame() to turn a tibble back to a data frame:
>
> class(as.data.frame(tbl_df(iris)))

You might get along by doing `p <- as.data.frame(p)` as well.

Comment: HAVB, this is actually not my question to accept an answer for, that would be Rospa above. This is my answer to their question.

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for the heads up, and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `p[, comorbid_names] == 1` will gave you the table of TRUE/FALSE values for your selected morbidities. To add the patient names or IDs to that list, use `cbind`, like this: `cbind(p["patient_id"], p[, comorbid_names] == 1)` where "patient_id" is the name of the column that identifies patients.

Here's a complete reproducible example:

```
comorbid_names <- c("chd", "heart_failure","stroke", "hypertension",
                    "diabetes", "copd", "epilepsy", "hypothyroidism", 
                    "cancer", "asthma", "ckd_stage3", "ckd_stage4",
                    "ckd_stage5", "atrial_fibrilation", "learning_disability",
                    "peripheral_arterial_disease", "osteoporosis")

all_morbidities <- c("chd", "heart_failure","stroke", "hypertension",
                    "diabetes", "copd", "epilepsy", "hypothyroidism", 
                    "cancer", "asthma", "ckd_stage3", "ckd_stage4",
                    "ckd_stage5", "atrial_fibrilation", "learning_disability",
                    "peripheral_arterial_disease", "osteoporosis",
                    "hairyitis", "jellyitis", "transparency")

# Create dummy data frame "p" with patient ids and whether or not they suffer from each condition  
patients <- data.frame(patient_id = 1:20)
conditions <- matrix(sample(0:1, nrow(patients)*length(all_morbidities), replace=TRUE),
                     nrow(patients),
                     length(all_morbidities))
p <- cbind(patients, conditions)
names(p) <- c(names(patients), all_morbidities)

# Final step: get patient IDs and whether they suffer from specific morbidities 
comorbidities <- cbind(p["patient_id"], p[, comorbid_names] == 1)
```

If you want to select only those patients that suffer from at least one of the morbidities, do this:

```
comorbidities[rowSums(comorbidities[-1]) != 0]
```